# Количество подключений через $_POST

Tags: php, html, javascript

Ребята, такой вопрос. Мы заполняем форму на странице и отправляем данные серверу, где эти данные обрабатывает скрипт. Как подсчитать количество подключений (к форме обработчика)?

Примерно так выглядит:

```
<form action="submit.php" method="post" name="form">      
<input id="name" type="text" name="name" placeholder="Имя *" class="name" />  
<input id="phone" type="text" name="phone" placeholder="Телефон *" class="phone" />  
<input id="but_call" class="red_button" name="send" type="submit" value="Получить!" />  
<span id="totla_text">Количество подключений: <span id="total">0</span></span>  
</form>
```

Вот он отправляется уже в submit.php. Как там подсчитать количество подключений и сохранить данные, при этом передать в id total?

```
if ($_POST == true) {  
   $i ++;  
}
```

Как передать `$i` обратно в index.html в тег `<span id="total">`?

Comment: @ggLike, Постарайтесь писать более развернутые вопросы. Поясните, в чем вы видите проблему, как ее воспроизвести и т. д.

Comment: @deivan я поправил код и уточнил вопрос!

Comment: $i будет всегда равен 1. Подключения надо хранить отдельно от скрипта, поскольку скрипт отработал - и умер.

Comment: @deivan данные обязательно нужно передать в тег обратно в файл index.html тогда все будет нормально!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Что мешает использовать AJAX?
AJAX'ом передали форму на сервер, обработали, увеличили $i, отправили ее обратно и вставили в span.

Примерный код:

```
//js
$(".red_button").on("click", function() {
    var form = $("[name=form]").serializeArray();
    $.post("submit.php", form, function (data) {
        $("#totla_text").text("Кол-во подключений: " + data['i']);
    }, "json");
});

//php
На php вы считается правильно $i, только оберните его в $response['i'] вместо $i,
затем:
echo json_encode($response);
```

Comment: @Влад Дяченко Я не пользуюсь Ajax и не совсем понимаю, как это будет работать, если бы вы дали более развернутый пример на основе моего кода, я бы подумал!

Comment: Думаю это самый оптимальный вариант! Спасибо @Влад Дяченко. Если у меня возникнут вопросы я обязательно прокомментирую!

Answer (score -1):

[Вот один из 100500 примеров, которые можно легко нагуглить.](http://www.php.su/articles/?cat=examples&page=011)

Comment: @deivan данный ответ на ваш вопрос является не уместным и даже грубым! Если вы не знаете ответ на вопрос не пишите!

Comment: По ссылке в моем ответе реальный пример, как организовать учет посещений ресурса. Если не хватает опыта понять этот пример - то ничто (кроме личной гордыни) не мешает попросить разъяснений, а не впадать в истерику.

Comment: @deivan ваш пример требует создании базы! Это совсем не то! Я дополнил вопрос, специально для вас. Мне требуется обратно передать в тег то, что делается в скрипте!

Comment: @ggLike, увы, но другого пути нет.

Comment: @deivan я, конечно, спорить не буду! Но считаю, что тут можно применить другой метод. Он заключается в чем: вытащить в Id=total данные и перенести в переменную, допустим, num (она и будет на некой базой, контейнер), дальше мы прибавили +1 к id и отправили данные обратно! Поэтому я тут вопрос и задал!

Comment: @ggLike, Ваш алгоритм не будет работать при нескольких одновременно обрабатываемых (запрошенных с разных браузеров) запросах.

Впрочем, с СУБД возможны те же проблемы.

Comment: @avp я понимаю, что это возможно, но вероятность такого исхода практически равна нулю!

Comment: @ggLike, у меня тесты в пятницу упали, потому что две создаваемые чуть ли не на соседних строчках даты все-таки отнеслись к разным секундам, а вы "практически равна нулю". Она будет равна нулю только при одном идеально работающем клиенте, а так каждый запрос с учетом задержек сети может легко дорасти до 200 мс - а это уже вероятность 1 к 4 при двух запросах в секунду.

Comment: @Etki, только наверное тесты *не упали*, а наоборот *прошли успешно*.

(теперь можно будет (как всегда в очередной раз) подправить систему)

--

Все-таки цель тестирования -- это поиск ошибок, а не демонстрация того, что все работает в рамках ТЗ.